# Rewrite a LINQ Query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have this query:

```
List<string> cat = new List<string>{'2'.'3','44'};
                        var storeEn = query1.AsEnumerable().
                            Where(ca => ca.CategoriesIds.Split(',',StringSplitOptions.None).
                            Any(x => cat.Contains(x)));
```

It is running but it is slow. Is there a way to change this query?

Comment: Remove `AsEnumerable`. And *don't store comma separated values* in the database. Use a proper database design. If you want to model a many-to-many relation, use a many-to-many table. There's no `if` or `but` about this. The query is slow because it loads the entire table in memory with `AsEnumerable()`. Everything after that happens on the client, without any benefit of indexing. An index on a comma-separated value wouldn't be used either. It's actually far easier to create a proper database design

Comment: In EF Core 5 such "join" tables can be [created and modeled automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many) from the relations between the main objects. Even in previous versions though, one can create the many-to-many class and have EF generate the table. Nothing is gained by storing related keys in a text field like this